# outputting 3 different signals from sound card

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

i am trying to generate 3 different Frequencies like (1.75k,2k,2.25k) in my pc using LabVIEW software.

but i'm getting only 2 outputs.

how to get 3rd output from my sound card. any one can help me plz

Comment: how can someone help you if we don't know your Soundcard model.

Comment: i am using inbuilt pc sound card... to get outputs

Comment: You still need to let us know what that sound card is. It has great bearing on what you can achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This will be possible if you have 5.1 onboard-sound, which most desktop PCs do these days. This is a little 'clumsy' to do with just onboard-sound, though:

If you get a programme like [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) you'll be able to set up three 'virtual cables'. Set up each as an output of whatever's generating your tones, and you should be able to individually route them to three output channels of your onboard soundcard, eg. Left, Right and Centre.

---

**Ideally:** Get a USB audio interface with enough output channels, such as the [M-Audio Mtrackquad](http://www.terapeak.com/worth/m-audio-mtrackquad-24-bit-4-channel-usb-midi-audio-interface-ath-m50x-headphones/351669463515/), and use audio software / DAW that's capable of routing signals to multiple outputs; [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/) is a cheap option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way you can get 3 outputs with a simple onboard card.

Could be possible with a 5.1 as stated. Never tried it myself though.

You need to search for an audio inferface that has 3(or more) *analog* outputs.

Im stressing analog because companies use outputs as a marketing bait and count midi,  spdf and other formats as well as outputs and monitor outs too,  so you end up buying a card with 40 outs in the advertisement and only 8 ouputs you can actually use(for most people)

Because you want it for scientific reasons a soundcard with 4 analog outpus will suit your needs, ruling out that you need 2 of them for monitors at all times.

Good luck